# keystore expire 1 day with an error: "Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect"

Tags: openssl, keystore, jks

I'm dealing with a problem about my keystore.

First I developed a secure connection between a java application and a cpp application, using openssl. I worked fine last month but in the past few days, it does not work fine.

I generate a pem and a key file with using openssl and I generate a keystore.jks by converting them, and it worked fine for 1-2 months when I tested it. But about 1 month later, I realize that the keystore does not work on the java side, failing with an exception. Two days ago I generated a new keystore and I tested it. It worked fine (both java and cpp parts). A day later, it didn't work.

I generated a new key store with using `-validty 16500`, and I expect that it will work but  today, it gives same error (copied below).

Has anyone seen this problem before which is about a keystore expiring in one day?

How can I solve this problem?

```
java.io.IOException: Keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at sun.security.provider.JavaKeyStore$JKS.engineLoad(Unknown Source)
at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
caused by: java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Password verification failed
... 13 more
2012-06-07 13:20:52,116 [           main]                       de
```

Answer (score 0):

Happened to me when the SDK changed / updated. Needed to build a new Keystore against the new JDK SDK (had to manually install JDK SE OSX)

Another strange issue I had was any key I created above 10000 was giving me a time exception.

Also make sure your country code is valid when generating your keystore.
http://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm (Dailing code listed here)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are providing correct store password and release password during signing your APK. Since same issue was earlier happening to me too.